# intelliJ automatically formating variables first

Tags: intellij-idea

with ctrl-alt-L I can format the code of a class which works fine.

Is there also a shortcut to automatically sort codelines so the variables comes first and methods later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action for this is Rearrange Code in the Code menu. It does not have a shortcut assigned by default, but you can assign one in Settings | Keymap.